# create list with negative value permutation

Tags: python, list, permutation

Can anyone help with creating lists with negative values out of a given list?

For example:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

Desired output would be

```
[[-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, 3], [1, 2, -3],[-1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-1, 2, -3], [-1, -2, -3]]
```

Comment: Why is `[1, 2, 3]` not a valid output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Produce the product of 3 times `[1, -1]` and multiply the result with your input list:

```
from itertools import product

values = [1, 2, 3]
[[num * mul for num, mul in zip(values, combo)]
 for combo in product([1, -1], repeat=len(values))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> values = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [[num * mul for num, mul in zip(values, combo)] for combo in product([1, -1], repeat=len(values))]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, -3], [1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, -3], [-1, -2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]]
```

The output order is slightly different from what you specified, but the same values are produced, plus the original list as the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it rather than having two list comprehensions is to like this

```
from itertools import *

print [[1*x[0], 2*x[1], 3*x[2]] for x in list(product([1,-1], repeat=3))]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, -3], [1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, -3], [-1, -2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]]
```

Since you know the values at the indexes of the list you can just multiply them by corresponding index in x. This however is not as flexible as using two list comprehensions like @Martijn's answer which can handle variable sized lists much easier.

Comment: but this doesn't really work with an arbitrary list of input values. Say you now want to do the same with `[42, 81]`. Then with `[1, 2, 4, 8]`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you are right which I addressed. I thought this was easier to read assuming the values weren't arbitrary. Your answer is more robust